# Как называется приём со словом «нет»?

Tags: терминология

На днях я катался на коньках, затем приехал домой, засунул в коньки нагревательные элементы и оставил сушиться. Коньки таким способом я сушил первый раз, поэтому спустя время попросил жену проверить: не плавятся ли они, не воняют ли они пластмассой?
Она сходила и сказала, что нет.
Но это "нет" прозвучало так, как будто они воняли чем-то другим. Как оказалось, ранее я плохо их просушил, в результате чего микроорганизмы оставили там следы своего пребывания, а жена совсем не ожидала такого сюрприза.

**Собственно вопрос**: как в русском языке называется приём, который использовала моя жена в своём ответе?

Comment: У девушек "да" значит "нет", а "нет" - "да".

Comment: Игра слов, наверное.